# Recursive method vs. a standard iterative method

Tags: algorithm

Is there a golden rule to follow when faced with a coding problem when you can't decide whether to use recursive method or a standard iterative method. Or when both option seem plausible or equally efficient in terms of memory, amount of code...est?

Comment: Recursion is useful for solving certain types of problems, but it has its downsides (code complexity, performance, stack overflow etc.) If it's not necessary I would avoid it.

Comment: As above, it is worth mentioning that recursive methods have stack overhead and will cause stack overflow errors if the call stack is too great. If this isn't a problem, I'd go with whichever seems like less of an engineering challenge. Some problems are best done with recursion, such as the 8 Queens problem, although it is entirely possible to do an iterative solution - it's just a headache. Recursive overhead is call stack frames and iterative overhead is usually smaller, so the amount of overhead in the recursive problem depends on the problem. My advice is to do what seems natural.

Answer (score 1):

Java isn't a functional programming language, and it doesn't provide facilities, such as tail recursion, that would be common in functional programming languages. So I'd say that for Java, prefer iteration in general, but if the iterative solution requires you to (say) manually maintain a stack or something similar, then use recursion.